# IOS: entitlement.plist for appstore process

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, entitlements

I know that for ADHoc version I should set in entitlement.plist a "NO" value in "get-task-allow", but for AppStore process? what I should to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For App Store also you need to set that to - `NO`.